# How to remove last element in set in dynamo?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

I have created a set using dynamoDB document client . I am able to remove items in this set however when i remove to the last element in the set nothing returns until i make a new post. Then all the other data is displayed.

```
    const params = {
      TableName: 'beta-user-' + process.env.NODE_ENV,
      Key: {
        username: request.username
      },
      UpdateExpression: "DELETE #features :feature",
      ExpressionAttributeNames: { "#features" : "features" },
      ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":feature": dynamodb.createSet([request.feature]) },
      ReturnValues: "NONE"
    };
```

and im calling it like

`const dynamoPromise = dynamodb.update(params).promise();
 return await dynamoPromise.then(result => { // stuff })`

The `UpdateExpression` i do not think is wrong 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.DELETE

I belive the problem is with `ExpressionAttributeValues` if i remove 
`dynamodb.createSet` I get many validation errors.

When i make a get request to app i get

```
{
    "message": [
        {
            "username": "x",
            "feature": [
                "blah",
                "test"
            ]
        },
        {
            "username": "z",
            "feature": [
                "blah"
            ]
        },
}
```

I make a delete request and remove the feature `test` from username `x`. This works and returns the same response minus the `test` feature. I make another delete request to remove `blah`. Blah is removed however when I make a `get` request I recieve:

```
{
    "message": {}
}
```

The other data is returned when i make a new post to that specific user.

EDIT:

I think the issue might be due to dynamo not liking an empty set

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with my return statement in my get request. I assumed that once features were deleted the record would be deleted. I was trying to return features on an object that had no features, therefore, it was erroring out and not returning anything.